# Clauses that start with "with" to provide additional information

Tags: clauses, dependent-clause

There are special classes of clauses to add additional information, and they start with "with". Consider the two following examples:\

> 1- The average consumption of three different nutrients is illustrated, with each represented in one of the three given pie charts.
> 2- Country X has the largest tea farms in the world, with its people exporting N tonnes of tea annually.

I want to know more about this type of clauses. For example, is it correct to change the first example as follows?

> The average consumption of three different nutrients is illustrated, with each being represented in one of the three given pie charts.
> or
> The average consumption of three different nutrients is illustrated, each represented in one of the three given pie charts.
> or
> The average consumption of three different nutrients is illustrated, each being represented in one of the three given pie charts.

Is it correct to change the second example as follows?

> The largest tea farms are in Country X, with its people exporting N tonnes of tea annually.
> or
> The highest rate of exporting tea accounts for Country X, with N tonnes exported annually.

When can we use such clauses?
What kind of relationship should exist between the subject of the independent clause and this type of clauses so that we can use them?
Are they considered as relative clauses?

Can you give me a book to learn about this particular form of clauses?

Comment: "With" is a preposition, so your examples commencing with _with_ are not clauses but PPs.

Comment: Just for clarity, that's prepositional phrases.

Comment: When you simplify sentence #1, you can remove *different* and *given*. Three different nutrients = three nutrients. The three given pie charts = the three pie charts.

Answer (score 1):

> There are special classes of clauses to add additional information, and they start with "with".
>
> with each represented in one of the three given pie charts.

> with its people exporting N tonnes of tea annually.

Both are prepositional phrases functioning as sentence adverbs - otherwise known as free modifiers.

You can test this by using the phrase to front the main clause.

Comment: Would you also discuss about the correctness of the changes I made to the examples so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The examples lack context and focus.